# Decode request's response in python

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

The response to my request looks as following:

```
alle_R={'items': [{'x':..., 'y'..., ...}, {...}...]}
```

I am trying to perform some Actions, as for example, to recall 'x' with help of `alle_R['items'][4]['x']`, but I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1022: invalid start Byte
```

I tried out this solution:

```
alle_R=str(alle_R)
encode_alle_R = codecs.encode(alle_R, 'utf-8')
```

while importing codecs of course. But this did not bring any results. Creating json files brings the same error.

Do you have any idea how I can access my elements?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: can you try stepping through the structure and checking the type. e.g.
`type(alle_R['items'])`, `type(alle_R['items'][4])` and so on. You might find that items list is storing an unexpected data type. I have experienced this before.

Comment: Please show the code that leads to the point where `alle_R` has the value you show (in other words: a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also: is this Python 2 or Python 3? Makes quite a difference when it comes to encoding.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. The Problem was a completely different data type than what I expected.